# IOS/Objective-C: Background save to core data after NSFetchedResultsController

Tags: ios, objective-c, thread-safety

After performing a sort using NSSortDescriptor on various attributes, I would like to capture the sort order and save it back to core data. To keep the uX steady, I am trying to do this in the background using a separate MOC.  However, I'm getting a mutated while enumerated error, possibly because several other things are going on--including syncing with a server and the FRC doing a fetch.

Can anyone see what might be wrong with my code?  Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

```
-(NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController {

//code to carry out fetch
//Sort order specified according to parameters

_theItems =[_fetchedResultsController fetchedObjects];
 //at this point fetch should be complete   
 NSManagedObjectContext *mainMOC = _managedObjectContext;
     NSManagedObjectContext*privateContext =[[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType];
    [privateContext setParentContext:mainMOC];
    [privateContext performBlock:^{

        for (int i = 0; i < _theItems.count; i++)
        {
            Items* oneitem = theItems[i];
            oneitem.sortorder = i;
        }

        NSError *error = nil;
        if (![privateContext save:&error]) {
            NSLog(@"Error saving context: %@\n%@", [error localizedDescription], [error userInfo]);
            abort();
        }
        [mainMOC performBlockAndWait:^{
            NSError *error = nil;
            if (![mainMOC save:&error]) {
                NSLog(@"Error saving context: %@\n%@", [error localizedDescription], [error userInfo]);
                //abort();
            }
            else {
                _managedObjectContext = mainMOC;
            }
        }];
    }];
    mainMOC=nil;
    privateContext = nil;

return _fectchedResultsController;
}
```

**Edit:**

From Apple docs:

```
NSArray *jsonArray = …; //JSON data to be imported into Core Data
NSManagedObjectContext *moc = …; //Our primary context on the main queue

NSManagedObjectContext *private = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType];
[private setParentContext:moc];

[private performBlock:^{
    for (NSDictionary *jsonObject in jsonArray) {
        NSManagedObject *mo = …; //Managed object that matches the incoming JSON structure
        //update MO with data from the dictionary
    }
    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![private save:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"Error saving context: %@\n%@", [error localizedDescription], [error userInfo]);
        abort();
    }
    [moc performBlockAndWait:^{
        NSError *error = nil;
        if (![moc save:&error]) {
            NSLog(@"Error saving context: %@\n%@", [error localizedDescription], [error userInfo]);
            abort();
        }
    }];
}];
```

**Edit 2:**

Placing the code in viewdidappear stopped the exception.  In addition, I changed the code to following and it "seems" to work.  Is this now thread safe?

```
 for (int i = 0; i < _theItems.count; i++)
            {
            Items* oneitem = theItems[i];
            NSManagedObjectID* oneID = oneitem.objectID;
            Items *myItem = [privateContext objectWithID:oneID];
            myItem.sortorder = i;

            }
```

Comment: I'm afraid something is very wrong here. It appears you have set up a private context and then iterate over a set of objects (subclasses of ManagedObject presumably?) which are from where? You haven't retrieved any objects using objectWithID on any of the variants of that method, so you are probably manipulating objects originally retrieved from your main context (and doing that within the performBlock call, so on the private context thread - ouch!). Then having manipulated objects from another context on the wrong thread, you try save the private context thinking it will all work. Nope.

Comment: I have also read that managed objects are not thread safe but object ids are so you need to to retrieve all your managed objects using objectwithID.  However, I also have read that NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType seems to have simplified this process and you can now do the above.  Maybe I misremember.  Will try to find reference.

Comment: This is what I read in the docs:  https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Concurrency.html

Comment: Yep the main context is on the main thread, the private context is on a background thread. You can't use objects from the main context on the background thread context. Manipulating main thread objects on a background thread will result in bad things happening in unpredictable ways. When you save the private context, the main thread objects you have edited won't be saved. They can only be saved by calling save on the main thread context (but don't do that - you manipulated them on a background thread). You need to pass the object id's to the private context and retrieve the objects by objectID

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access NSManagedObjects from multiple contexts. Assuming `[NSFetchedResultsController fetchedObjects]` returns objects owned by `_managedObjectContext`, you cannot then access them from `privateContext`.

One option might be to pass the NSManagedObjectIDs to the private MOC and use the ID to query the main MOC for the corresponding object.

Does that make sense?

Comment: are the fetched objects in the FRC automatically managed objects?

Comment: Yes. From [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nsfetchedresultscontroller/1622278-fetchedobjects?language=objc): _"The results array reflects the in-memory state of managed objects in the controller’s managed object context"_

Comment: The error no longer appears when I move the code to viewdidload.  I do actually want the temporary order from the FRC, NSArray *theItems or in this case _theItems.  Can you suggest code to use the objectforid?  I guess it would go in the loop as I grab each sortOrder from the array.

Comment: I think your answer is correct, but would you mind checking my code above to see if it is in fact thread safe?  it is no longer throwing exception but that may be because of something else such a moving the code to viewdidappear.

Comment: Technically, that code block is not thread safe because if it was invoked from multiple threads, it would be accessing the same objects. However, in practice you might not have that problem because I believe viewDidLoad will be called from the main thread. Just a suggestion: rather than asking how to get this particular code snippet to work, you might be better off updating your question to ask the high-level goal you want to accomplish and provide this code to show what you have already tried. It's hard to make suggestions for this code without some understanding of the surrounding context.